# Android AlphabetIndexer English and Hebrew(Unicode) togather

Tags: android, listview, unicode, indexer

Following is my listview adapter classes using AlphabetIndexer.
It does not work when I add unicode chars (for hebrew) togather with the english.
I get exception in: getSectionForPosition. getting to index -1....
Tries it with 2 entries in the DB - 1 starting with hebrew char (unicode) and one with english. The first char for AlphabetIndexer was the unicode char.
Really really need help in this one....

```
public abstract class RecipeListViewAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements SectionIndexer
{
    protected   Context                         mContext;
    protected   Cursor                          mCursor;
    private     LayoutInflater                  mInflater;

    public static final int TYPE_HEADER = 1;
    public static final int TYPE_NORMAL = 0;

    private static final int TYPE_COUNT = 2;

    private AlphabetIndexer indexer;

    private int[] usedSectionNumbers;

    private Map<Integer, Integer> sectionToOffset;
    private Map<Integer, Integer> sectionToPosition;

    protected ImageLoader   mImageLoader        = new ImageLoader( MyApp.Instance() );


    public RecipeListViewAdapter(   Context     context, 
                                    int         layout, 
                                    Cursor      c,
                                    String[]    from, 
                                    int[]       to ) 
    {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);

        mContext            = context;
        mCursor             = c;
        mInflater           = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        indexer             = new AlphabetIndexer(c, c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NAME"), "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
        sectionToPosition   = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
        sectionToOffset     = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        final int count = super.getCount();

        int i;
        for( i = count - 1 ; i >= 0; i-- )        
        {
            sectionToPosition.put(indexer.getSectionForPosition(i), i);
        }

        i = 0;
        usedSectionNumbers = new int[sectionToPosition.keySet().size()];

        for( Integer section : sectionToPosition.keySet() )
        {
            sectionToOffset.put(section, i);
            usedSectionNumbers[i] = section;
            i++;
        }

        for(Integer section: sectionToPosition.keySet())
        {
            sectionToPosition.put(section, sectionToPosition.get(section) + sectionToOffset.get(section));
        }
    }

     @Override
     public int getCount() 
     {
         if( super.getCount() != 0 )
         {
             return super.getCount() + usedSectionNumbers.length;
         }

         return 0;
     }

     @Override
     public Object getItem(int position) 
     {
         if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_NORMAL) //we define this function later
         {
             return super.getItem( GetItemPosition( position ) );
         }

         return null;
     }

     public int GetItemPosition( final int position )
     {
         return position - sectionToOffset.get(getSectionForPosition(position)) - 1;
     }

     public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
         if (! sectionToOffset.containsKey(section)){
             int i = 0;
             int maxLength = usedSectionNumbers.length;

             while (i < maxLength && section > usedSectionNumbers[i]){
                 i++;
             }
             if (i == maxLength) return getCount();

             return indexer.getPositionForSection(usedSectionNumbers[i]) + sectionToOffset.get(usedSectionNumbers[i]);
         }

         return indexer.getPositionForSection(section) + sectionToOffset.get(section);
     }

     public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
         int i = 0;     
         int maxLength = usedSectionNumbers.length;

         while (i < maxLength && position >= sectionToPosition.get(usedSectionNumbers[i])){
             i++;
         }
         return usedSectionNumbers[i-1];
     }

     public Object[] getSections() {
         return indexer.getSections();
     }

     //nothing much to this: headers have positions that the sectionIndexer manages.
     @Override
     public int getItemViewType(int position) {
         if (position == getPositionForSection(getSectionForPosition(position))){
             return TYPE_HEADER;
         } return TYPE_NORMAL;
     }

     @Override
     public int getViewTypeCount() {
         return TYPE_COUNT;
     }



    @Override
    public View getView(    int         position, 
                            View        convertView, 
                            ViewGroup   parent ) 
    {
        final int type = getItemViewType(position);
        if (type == TYPE_HEADER)
        {
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.header, parent, false);
            }
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.header)).setText((String)getSections()[getSectionForPosition(position)]);
            return convertView;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

            if (convertView == null) 
            {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recipes_list_view_entry, null);

                holder.name             = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById( R.id.name_entry );
                holder.author           = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById( R.id.username_entry );
                holder.ratingBar        = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById( R.id.list_RatingBarId );
                holder.userRatingBar    = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById( R.id.list_userRatingBarId );
                holder.diffculty        = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.list_DifficultyImageViewId );
                holder.preparationTime  = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.list_TimeImageViewId );
                holder.recipePic        = new DisplayableImageView( (ImageView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.list_RecipeImageViewId ) );

                holder.name.setTypeface(  MyApp.Fonts.ARIAL );
                holder.name.setTextSize(  MyApp.Fonts.RUNNING_TEXT_SIZE );
                holder.name.setTextColor( Color.BLACK );
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            if( super.getItem( GetItemPosition(position) ) != null )
            {
                // Check if single
                if( getCount() == position+1 && position == 1 )
                {
                    convertView.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.list_single );
                }
                else if( getItemViewType(position-1) == TYPE_HEADER )
                {
                    // Check if single item in the middle of the list
                    if( getItemViewType(position+1) == TYPE_HEADER )
                    {
                        convertView.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.list_single );
                    }
                    else if( position == getCount() - 1 )
                    {
                        convertView.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.list_single );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        convertView.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.list_up );
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Middle or bottom
                    convertView.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.list_middle );
                    //If not last
                    if( getCount() != position + 1 )
                    {
                        // Check if middle or down
                        if( getItemViewType(position+1) == TYPE_HEADER )
                        {
                            convertView.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.list_down );
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            convertView.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.list_middle );
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // If it is last - use list_down
                        convertView.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.list_down );
                    }

                }

                FillRecipeDataToHolder( GetItemPosition(position), holder );

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } 
            else 
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    //these two methods just disable the headers
    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_HEADER){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    protected abstract void FillRecipeDataToHolder(int position, ViewHolder holder);

    static class ViewHolder 
    {
        TextView                separator;
        DisplayableImageView    recipePic;
        TextView                name;
        TextView                author;
        RatingBar               ratingBar;
        RatingBar               userRatingBar;
        ImageView               diffculty;
        ImageView               preparationTime;
        TextView                serveCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am doing something similiar HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224233/alphabetindexer-with-custom-adapter-managed-by-loadermanager